# load xib outlets to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Viewcontoller called `BookingMain` and in the run time it will subview the xib called `BookingForm` to it. 
in `BookingForm` there are outlets `fullName, Email, Telephone`.

im trying to access these outlets from my `BookingMain`.

So what i have done is under `@implementation BookingMain` i added `BookingForm *book;`
 then tried to access those `BookingForm` out lets this way.

```
NSString *Name;
book.fullName.text = Name;

//book.fullName.text : this is always null
```

but it gives me null value.

im new to iOS and couldn't figure it out.

Updated :

`.H file`

```
@interface BookingForm : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *fullName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *email;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phone;
```

`.m File`

```
#import "BookingForm.h"

@implementation BookingUserDetails

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {

        NSString *xib = @"BookingForm";

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:xib owner:self options:nil];

        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }

    return self;

}

@end
```

Comment: Somewhere, you need to create a BookingForm object and assign it to the "book" pointer.  How do you go about loading the BookingForm xib file?

Comment: `userDetails = [[BookingForm alloc] init];
    [viewContactForm addSubview:userDetails];`

Comment: Could you show the code you have the BookingForm Class?

Comment: @Cade  Assigning to `userDetails` doesn't set the `book` variable.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check here :

- When you are creating the BookingForm, using [BookingForm alloc] init]; You are calling the init method. So add an init method and replicate the code you currently have in the initWithCoder method.
- In the code you have below, you are **just declaring** a variable called Name. At this point its is still nil since the Name has not be allocated or initialized. When you assign this to book.fullName.text, this is also going to be nil.

  ```
  NSString *Name;
  book.fullName.text = Name;
  //book.fullName.text : this is always null
  ```

Comment: I tried like this too. `NSLog(@"%@",book.fullName.text);` still nill. that means that outlets are not connected right?